# Remove a property using object destructuring, without eslint no-unused-vars error

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, destructuring, unused-variables

Consider the following code where I create a "copy" of `x` with one of the properties removed, using destructuring:

```
const x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const { a, ...x2} = x;
console.log(x);
console.log(x2);
```

If I do it like this, `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` will consider it an error that `a` is not used.

How can I change the code to fix the error, without explicitly asking eslint to ignore the offending line, preferably still using the destructuring syntax? I.e. I really don't want to use `delete`, nor do I want to explicitly enumerate all other properties like `const x2 = {b: x.b, c: x.c }`.

Is there a fancy syntax or weird eslint rule to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: Why not just add an ignore pattern to the rule config and use that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [newly added option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings) named `ignoreRestSiblings` for that rule.

You could set it to true to ignore your case:

```
{ "ignoreRestSiblings": true }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually remove some props with this util:

```js
const removeProperty = <Obj, Prop extends keyof Obj>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop) => {
  const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest
}
```

Please check if it works for your case.

The trick is that you use underscore `_` for unused variables.

You can allow explicitly using of `_` in eslint rules.

Comment: linting is supposed to help keep the code pretty, not force you to introduce idiosyncrasies to dance around poorly written rules.  `ignoreRestSiblings` is a much better approach because removing properties with destructuring is concise.

Comment: @Wyck, sure, you are right